# Multiple filters with same url mapping

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

Is it possible to use two filters that have the same url-mapping?

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>TeeFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>filter1r</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>TeeFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
<display-name>CredentialsFilter</display-name>
<filter-name>CredentialsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>filter2</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>CredentialsFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. You can.

The order you placed in web.xml will execute.

So here,

First control goes to `TeeFilter` and then to `CredentialsFilter`.

And if you want to execute  `CredentialsFilter` first, change the order in web.xml

Comment: I was only working with CredentialsFilter and once I added the TeeFilter which is just a logback logger for logging http requests and responses, some of the services stopped working and others are still working. Do you have any idea why would this happen?

Comment: @mosaad Yes, That's really weird. It should not happen. Do you observer the order of execution? and any exceptions ?

Comment: order of execution does not make a difference and the log file created says that a 204 Response was received

Comment: old question missing an important point: you need a
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
in your public void doFilter(...)

Answer (score 2):

When using annotation ,it seems like it  compares the two filters lexicographically.And then choose the one that comes first according to this comparison.
Example
I tried with two filters named **Filter1.java** and **Filter2.java**.Both filters  have the same url-mapping. When  I invoke  the mapped url,**Filter1.java** executes first.But When I rename Filter1.java to **Filter3.java**. Then **Filter2.java** executes first.
To be more clear. If you have 2 filters A and B.When using annotation to map the same url,A will always execute first.
Can you try if you can achieve this result like me.Thanks.If not let me know

Comment: If you are using annotations from spring I believe @Order may be used to override the lexical order. This answer is a good addition to the original question.